# background service in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, service

I am trying to create a service which runs in the background and watch for URL change and sends the new params to various controllers.

I understand I need to start this service in app.run so that it is started right at the beginning.
I am not using ng-router provider, and so i am not using $locationchangesuccess or $stateChangeStart.
Furthermore i cannot use $scope.$watch as this is a service.

Any idea?

Comment: do you use a routing module (`ngRoute` or `ui.router`)? I think what you need is to use `$routeParams` (/ `$stateParams`), which will collect parameters from the url as specified in your config. E.g. `some/path/:id` can accept a URL `#!/some/path/10`, where `$routeParams.id` will be `10`. Getting it into controller would need you to simply inject `$routeParams`

Comment: thanks but the routing is implemented backend so i dont need to use ui-router.

Comment: why the minus? LOL , some self righteous knight happened to brisk around endowed with his light saber on his faithful white horse, proclaimed a (-1) engraved with his sword, but never said word ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe do a `$watch`:

```
angular.module('myModule', []).run(myUrlWatcher);

function myUrlWatcher($rootScope, $location) {
    'ngInject';
    $rootScope.$watch(function () {
        return $location.url();
    }, function () {
        /// ....
        console.log('in-app url changed, do wahtever you want to do here')
        // ....
    })
}
```

Comment: thanks - can you write it without functional syntax?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by without functional syntax, but yep. I added the code for you. You're welcome :)

Comment: thanks man! however i get this error `Error: [$rootScope:infdig]`  which is basically due to `{0} $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: {1}`

Comment: basically, the $watch fire many times when i start the app which leads to that error, while $location.url() when not have yet params after the slash / , and then it keeps firing for some reason.. perhaps i need to put some sort of conditional? but i shouldn't put $watch within an "if statement" i think...

Comment: i used your example word for word and it worked. however it seems to fire only once when i start the app. (console log prints only once) when i change url no firing happens

Comment: HI again! firstly, you're right! it doesn't mean much to put a watch inside an if statement, even it may not mean much (and mean bad) to put an if statement inside your watch expression : ))) . 

But for the second matter, I tried it again and seems to be working in my situation. : ) its strange. I will try to provide a jsFiddle/codepen later today (i am busy right now) but if you can provide one, do it and we will discuss on it. huh ?

Comment: i am having a hard time passing the value of the url back to the controller. it comes up as undefined. any trick? i am trying to use promises right now

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by 'passing the value of the url back to controller'. the controller can have it's own `$location` and exploit that. here: I created a codepen : https://codepen.io/Ardeshir81/pen/PBNBgB?editors=0010               tell me what you want to happen in there

Comment: thanks so much man, i didnt see till now - iam going to look and give you feedback